# Do we need to sign the NPAPI plug-ins for Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, npapi, osx-mountain-lion

I have an NPAPI based plug-in. Do I have to sign it to make it work on Mountain Lion? I know the documentation says we need to sign the application if it isn't part of App Store. Does the requirement holds true for plug-ins?

I am asking this because, I haven't seen any issues while testing my plug-in in Mountain Lion. Does anybody has any ideas on this?

Regards,

Vishvesh

Comment: The documentation for this is under NDA, so nobody can give a detailed public answer at this point, except on devforums.apple.com. However, even from the public documentation, and the implementation that's included in 10.7.3 and 10.7.4 but disabled, it's clear that Gatekeeper applies only to launching applications, which means it isn't going to affect NPAPI plugins.

Answer (score 3):

The public information on Gatekeeper implies that it only affects applications, not things like plug-ins. However, there is no firm answer beyond that implication.

If you're a Mac Developer Program member under NDA, this has been discussed on the forums, and you can find the answer there (https://devforums.apple.com/community/mac/pre), but nobody is allowed to copy that information anywhere else.

Comment: I will sign the plug-in since it won't take a lot of time or effort. Better be safe.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. You're _supposed_ to sign all publicly-released binaries, no matter what, it's just that the OS doesn't check. If you've got an MDP membership, I'd read up on the details of Developer ID, and look at the designated requirements that Xcode 4.3.2 or 4.4DR generates when it auto-signs apps for Developer ID.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the plug-in after signing it using sudo spctl -a -v. It seems to be fine.